# How to remove index.php from wordpress wp-admin login url

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

In my recent wordpress install  i can not logged in  wp-admin and all styles gone in login page because index.php is adding in all url  like 
http://examples.com/index.php/wp-includes/css/buttons.min.css

so how can i remove index.php from url

.htaccess seems fine:

```
   # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>             
   # END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `.htaccess` is missing one important line: exclude `index.php` from rule

Here is the default one:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

From http://dejanjanosevic.info/remove-index-php-permalink-in-wordpress/

> The thing to check is config file for Apache which can also override your
>   .htaccess directives. Look for Ubuntu default:
>   **/etc/apache2/apache2.conf** file and change the entry for / and /var/www
>   from **AllowOverride None** to **AllowOverride All**. Then restart Apache
>   server and hopefully it can solve the issue